# Selenium WebDriver Screenshot does not capture the web page footer

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I use Selenium Webdriver to take screenshot in my web page with the provided URL.
It captures the full web page but it failed to capture the footer of the web page.

[image]

How to fix this issue?
this is my code:

```
browser.get('http://leadplus.net/')
browser.set_window_size(width,height)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(path_save_image)
```

Comment: don't post so many screenshots

Comment: so sorry. Because I want people to see the error I need to resolve

Comment: Can post your code?

Comment: @frianH

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-no-sandbox-job")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars') 
width = 1280
height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight")
browser.get('https://leadplus.net/')
browser.set_window_size(width,height)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(path_save_image)

Comment: Please edit your question with your code above, not comment.

Comment: @frianH i using base code in my question

Answer (score 1):

call the `.save_screenshot()` method on your `WebDriver` instance instead of on `WebElement`:

```
driver = WebDriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.save_screenshot('/path/to/screenshot.png')
```

Comment: I have found the cause of the problem  
To scroll page then  the footer to display  
So when shooting the screen will not capture the footer  
I am trying to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to change your screenshot dimensions. You could try changing the browser size, which should also set the correct dimensions for taking the screenshot.

```
driver.set_window_size(width, height)
```

`800,600` are common parameters.